# What is the best way to load only 1 page over https in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, https, getusermedia

In my laravel application I need one page to be over https because I want the user to use his microphone.

*The method getUserMedia and is currently only allowed over https https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins*

For performance I only want this page that does audio recording to be over https. But that also means that I need to load all my assets over https with 'secure_asset' in this page only. That means I will have something like this in my master blade for all my assets:

```
@if(Request::is('record'))

   <script type="text/javascript" src="{{secure_asset('/js/jquery.js')}}"></script>

@else

   <script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('/js/jquery.js')}}"></script>

@endif
```

What is the best and cleanest way to achieve this with laravel routing?

Comment: For performance reason, if you can use spdy or http2, you should use HTTPS, it's faster than http in these case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `'https' => true]` in your `routes.php` just for this one route/page - that seems very clean to me.

Example:

```
Route::post('/yourroute', ['uses' => 'YourController@method', 'https' => true]);
```

**Update**
You can also use the `.htaccess` file in your `public` folder.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Redirect specific route to HTTPS
    # The rule is looking for the content between ^ and $ and if found in the URL it redirects to https://www.example.com/yourroute
    RewriteRule ^yourroute$ https://www.example.com/yourroute [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

And yes, for your assets you need to have an if-else statement as you already using. You can either use `secure_asset()` `asset(..., true)` helper.

Comment: And load in the assets like I referred in the question?

Comment: No. The assets can still be loaded via `asset` just with the second param to be `true`. See `function asset($path, $secure = null)` - the asset method takes a second param that is normally `null` but can be set to true to load assets via HTTPS

Comment: I did it like this and it still goes over http :  Route::get('/record', ['as' => 'record', 'uses' => 'RecordController@index', 'https' => true]);

Comment: Sorry @JimPeeters! It seems there Laravel did some changes regarding that. Probably an easier/faster solution is to use the `.htaccess` with `RewriteRule ^yourroute$ https://www.example.com/yourroute [L,R=301]`

Comment: what does the '^yourroute$' stand for? is there a way to call the base url (for when switching to development mode to online host?) like this : RewriteRule https://{{BASEURL}}/record [L,R=301]

Comment: '^yourroute' stands for this route you want to call via HTTPS, it is a pattern. For details about the `RewriteRule` directive see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule Unfortunately there is no such mechanism with a placeholder like {{BASE URL}}. What the rule does: It searches for the content between _^_ and _$_ and the do a redirect

Comment: I made these changes now : RewriteRule ^yourroute$ https://www.gloops-alpha-jimpeeters.c9users.io/record [L,R=301] and in routes.php : Route::get('/record', ['as' => 'record', 'uses' => 'RecordController@index', 'https' => true]);    But when i click a link with href="{{ route('record') }}" it doesn't go to https